# return values for .Items in kubernetes

Tags: go

Printing e gives some numbers what does that .items returning.please attach any references for it if possible

```
func Homepage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    NamespaceStruct := NamespaceDetails{}
    for e, Namespaces := range NamespaceClient.Items {
        NamespaceStruct.Namespace = append(NamespaceStruct.Namespace, Namespaces.Name)
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "homepage2.html", NamespaceStruct)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range` loop in Go can iterate over *map* or *slices*.

*Map* resources are quite similar to key/value dictionaries, so expecting something like:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "bizz": "buzz"
}
```

*Slice* ones, instead, are just items pushed into a stack, similar to array ones:

```
[
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "bizz",
  "buzz"
]
```

Said that, and since we don't have enough context (e.g.: `what is NamespaceClient?`), I'm pretty sure that `Items` is just a *slice* (aka as array) and iterating over it, two values are returned for each iteration.

As you noticed, the first is the *index*, and the second is a copy of the element at that index.